# Struggling to get my animations to work on my first game

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I am trying to make my first game and have been struggling to get my animations to work.
I have been following along with a YouTube course and when it came to coding the animations on Unity i cannot seem to get it to work.
Please can someone who understands coding and Unity have a look at the following screenshots and help me out.

This is my code for my game:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed;

    private Vector3 input;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        input = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Verical"));
        Rigidbody.AddForce(input * moveSpeed);
    }
}
```

I cannot get the white dot next to my Player Control script to light up and it will not work.
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Your question is about animation but I do not see anything related to an Animator in your code? What have you done so far to animate the character? And when you say animate, do you just mean move? Are there errors or what is the exact issue you are experiencing?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context on the PlayerControl script and the "white dot", so we can understand exactly what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to change the script, then this is how I would do it:

```
Rigidbody rb;

void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}
void Update()
{
    float speed = 10f;
    float x = Input.GetAxis(“Horizontal”) * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    float z = Input.GetAxis(“Vertical”) * speed * Time.deltaTime;

    rb.AddForce(x, 0f, z);
}
```

And freeze rotation along the x and a axis to not fall over. You can do this in the rigidbody component.

Comment: I think you probably want to declare "rb" at class level, otherwise it won't work ;)

Comment: Not sure... I always do it at class level, but it should work in a method.

Comment: If the variable is declared in a method, it won't be accessible outside that method.